# Аналог NFS (распределенное сетевое хранилище) для Windows 7

Tags: windows, сеть

Здравствуйте!

В сети есть один сервер под Ubuntu (DHCP + DC + smb) и один **[NAS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAS)**. На NAS делается бэкап с сервера, а он сам не бэкапится. В то же время клиентских машин уже под 50 и на них в принципе есть как минимум по 50-100 Гб не используемого места. Нужно организовать распределенное файловое хранилище.
В связи с тем что все машины (кроме сервера и шлюза) под *Windows XP/7*, то нужен инструмент который можно было использовать на них (аналог **[NFS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)**).

Вопрос в том каким ПО под Windows XP/7 можно организовать распределенное сетевое хранилище?

***PS***
Небольшую [подборку (*opennet.ru*)](http://www.opennet.ru/prog/sml/150.shtml) ПО я уже нашел - по возможности опробую, но меня интересует советы людей реально работавших / работающих с подобным.

Comment: Идея состоит не в том что бы делать бэкапы в распределенную сетевую файловую систему, а использовать её в качестве основной шары (задействовать планируется только постоянно включенные компьютеры), а  бэкапы делать на NAS...

Answer (score 3):

Хреновая это идея. Все распределенные ФС крайне не любят выпадения нод. А винды будут регулярно ребутаться. В итоге вся эта конструкция со временем упадет или потеряет половину файлов.

Comment: В сети есть несколько машин которые работают постоянно (на них стоят несколько серверов - SQL и т.д), и если они перегружаются, то все вместе.   По идею основным критерием для распределенных ФС должна быть устойчивость к отключению узлов за счет избыточности - как, например, у [Tahoe][1], по крайней мере согласно [описанию][2] (лично не проверял).    О том чем чревато использование такой ФС я в курсе. Меня интересует реальный опыт использования распределенных ФС есть у кого-то или таковых нет?  [1]: http://allmydata.org/trac/tahoe  [2]: http://www.opennet.ru/prog/sml/150.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Настоящая распределённая сетевая файловая система, на сколько мне известно, штука весьма сложная, требовательная и вообще. В общем это не то что стоит использовать в вашей ситуации.

Наверное будет лучше сообразить какий-то велосипед раскидывающий бекапы по smb-шарам на виндовых машинах (с учётом свободного места на них). Можно не умничать и раскидывать бекапы рандомно по тем шарам на которых ещё осталось достаточно места  (для удобства можно потом собирать всё это в кучу каким-то AUFS-ом), а можно соорудить что-то замороченное с репликацией бекапов на несколько хостов.

Но в целом эта затея с бекапом на клиентские машины кажется мне чреватой осложнениями.

Comment: Это я уже обдумывал, но идея несколько в другом (см. комментарий к вопросу).   Сейчас меня интересует именно софт которым реально кто-то пользовался, что бы попробовать и приступить к реализации или точно сказать, что это плохая идея и обосновать начальству целесообразность отдельного smb сервера.

Comment: Нормальные сетевуе распределённые файловые системы это сложно, любые распределённые системы это сложно, а уж распределённая сетевая ФС используемая как обычная ФС (без оглядки на неё природу) и построенная поверх очень ненадёжного оборудования это полный ахтунг. Да и едва-ли кто-то будет заморачиваться написанием чего-то подобного под винды.

Comment: Почему же, такие софтины есть. Вот даже [сайт][1] с подборкой.  Другие дело использует ли их кто-то для реальных задач...  Потому и задаю вопрос...  [1]: http://www.opennet.ru/prog/sml/150.shtml